# How to read and print only one line from source code in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to read only one line from the code
so by using `node.js` I:

```
import fs = require('fs');
```

then:

```
var output = fs.readFileSync('/direction/projectname/server.js','utf8');
console.log(output);
```

I output this way whole file from this direction... BUT I WANT TO PRINT ONLY ONE SPECIFIC LINE OF THAT SOURCE CODE, for example, 51st line.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: `console.log(output.split('\n')[50])`

Comment: How does this task involve `sweet.js` or the `npm` or some `stack-trace`? Please don't spam keywords/tags. It won't give you more attention, it will get you downvotes.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for misleading tags npm and sweet.js, I wanted to include something more but I mix up, I will pay more attention next time. And I thought that stack-tracer might be answer for the problem. Anyway, THANK YOU very much.